# DateTime c# parsing

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I try to parse DateTime.TryParse("30-05-2010"), and it throws an exception because it accepts MMddyyyy, and I need ddMMyyyy format. how can I change TryParse format?

thanks,

Dani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making that adjustment because of local usage, try this:

```
bool success = DateTime.TryParse("30-05-2010", out dt);

Console.Write(success); // false

// use French rules...
success = DateTime.TryParse("30-05-2010", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
              System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt);

Console.Write(success); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method instead which allows you to specify the exact format the string is in

Comment: This is best if any deviation (such as "30-5-2010") is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the overload with the formatprovider.

```
DateTime.TryParse("30-05-2010", <IFormatProvider>)
```

not sure how to correctly implement it, cant test anything here,  but here's more info about the iformatprovider:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx