# Why is DateTime.TryParse() returning true for the culture "en-NZ" when MMddyyyy is passed in?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following code:

```
DateTime.TryParse("06-28-2012", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-NZ"),
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
```

I'm not sure why this is returning true since if I go into my Regional Settings in Windows, I only see the following date formats under short date:

- d/MM/yyyy
- d/MM/yy
- dd/MM/yy
- d.MM.yy
- yyyy-MM-dd

So then why is a short date format like MM-dd-yyyy returning true? Shouldn't it return false?

I'm using this similar post as a source: [DateTime c# parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816958/datetime-c-sharp-parsing)

Important:
Please note that I also have my regional settings set to use English (New Zealand) and chose 
yyyy-MM-dd as my short date format.

Comment: This returns false on mine. Same [here](http://ideone.com/JeKCk6). How are you testing it?

Comment: Using Immediate Window on VS2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your short date format set to `yyyy-MM-dd` is the cause of this behavior (I do not know if that the standard in New Zealand, but New Zealand's short date is set to `d/MM/yyyy` on my computer). I do not know if Dot Net, or the underlying Windows APIs are to blame, but it seems like it's smart enough to understand that the 4-digits part represents the year, and after that it just preserves the month-day order (Note that calling `DateTime.TryParse("28-06-2012")` will actually fail).

You can try using ParseExact, but be warned that will fail on a slightest change of the string (for example, when using a dot or a slash as a separator, instead of a dash.

In my opinion, it's probably best to leave the behavior as is, as it can handle more cases, but if you really must check if a date string was in a specified (yet flexible) format, Regex is the best option. For example `Regex.IsMatch("2012/06/28", @"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][./\\][0-9][0-9]?[./\\][0-9][0-9]?");` should suit your needs, while still allowing some flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Could you execute and post the result from the code below?

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator;
```

Comment: First one is "yyyy-MM-dd". Second one is "-"